# Как спарсить данные из таблицы html через?

Tags: php, html, парсер

У меня PHP скрипт формирует таблицу в html файле, с такой структурой для каждой строки таблицы

```
<tr>
<td id="1" style="width:810"></td>
<td id="2" style="width:4969"></td>
<td id="3" style="width:2323"></td>
<td id="4" style="width:810"></td>
<td id="5" style="width:810"></td>
<td id="6" style="width:1000"></td>
<td id="7" style="width:783"></td>
<td id="8" style="width:783"></td>
<td id="9" style="width:783"></td>
<td id="10" style="width:783"></td>
<td id="11" style="width:1566"></td>
</tr>
```

Подскажите как из этой таблицы получить данные по определённым ячейкам , например по тем , которые id=2, id =3, id =7. Я пробовал парсером "Simple html dom parser" вот так :

```
    foreach($html->find('#2 #3') as $a){
            $naimen =$a->innertext;
//**тут проверка на пустоту, т.к некоторые строки не содержат данных*/
            if (iconv_strlen($naimen) >0 ) { 
                $index++;
                $activeSheet->setCellValue('A'.$index, $index);
                $activeSheet->setCellValue('D'.$index, $naimen);
            }
    }
```

Но данный парсер возвращает всё единым массивом, подскажите, есть ли другие методы парсинга или как модифицировать запрос в данном парсере? Т.е можно ли как то элементы собрать в один двумерный, или в разные массивы ?

Comment: У меня другой вопрос: зачем формировать таблицу и потом из неё вытягивать данные, если можно сразу необходимые данные использовать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский сначала данные изначально собираются из таблицы Ворд файла, поэтому решил сначала в такую структуру сформировать, блин, а ведь вы сейчас навели меня на мысль что не обязательно в хтмль сохранять, ведь можно в другой формат. Просто из Форд-файла всё собирается  путём добавления текста в одну строку, т.е в одну строковую переменную собираются все данные из таблицы

Comment: *"Просто из Форд-файла всё собирается путём добавления текста в одну строку, т.е в одну строковую переменную собираются все данные из таблицы "*  --- соберите эти данные нормально, в какой-нибудь массив или любую удобную структуру данных, которую можно читать. А потом просто её используйте.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это невозможно с тем парсером. Вопрос решил

Answer (score 0):

Решается вот так - проходм по строкам, и потом уже элементы с id вставялем куда нужно

```
if($html->innertext!='' and count($html->find('tr'))) {

    foreach ($html->find('tr') as $pub) {
        $title = $pub->find('#2', 0);
        $marka = $pub->find('#3', 0);
        $ed = $pub->find('#4', 0);
   }
}
```